# How to place figure after sentence and not within?

Tags: floats, positioning

I guess as most of you know, figure placing in Latex is sometimes a bit painful. During my experience with Latex I learnt a lot about floating boxes and all the nasty stuff for a forced placing like `[htb]` etc. and finally I found a suitable way for me to have the flexibility for floating but also putting the figure near the place I wanted. 
But also I encounter sometimes (but only sometimes) that Latex puts the figure within a sentence and not afterwards. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,DIV12]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
%
\begin{figure}[h!]
\rule{\textwidth}{0.5cm}
\caption[indention=0pt]{Example 1}
\vspace*{5.8mm}
\end{figure}
%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum.\par
Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.
%
\begin{figure}[h!]
\rule{\textwidth}{0.5cm}
\caption[indention=0pt]{Example 2}
\vspace*{5.8mm}
\end{figure}
%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum.\par
Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.
%
\begin{figure}[h!]
\rule{\textwidth}{0.5cm}
\caption[indention=0pt]{Example 3}
\vspace*{5.8mm}
\end{figure}
%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum.\par
Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.
%
\begin{figure}[h!]
\rule{\textwidth}{0.5cm}
\caption[indention=0pt]{Example 4}
\vspace*{5.8mm}
\end{figure}
%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum.\par
Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.
\end{document}
```

I found the first picture interesting, because it is placed after the `\lipsum[1]`, but the second picture, which has the same text as `\lipsum[1]` before it, is placed within a sentence.

So now I am wondering, why is this happening and how can I avoid this without adding any more vertical space with `\par` etc?

Also thanks for your patience with the MWE!

Comment: If you can't reproduce the issue using some real code for folks to study, then how are the readers of your query supposed to diagnose the problem -- let alone offer a cure? Could you maybe state that a page break is involved either immediately before the start of the figure (in which case the figure is presumably at the top of a page) or immediately after the end of the figure (in which caes the figure is likely at the bottom of a page)?

Comment: @ Mico, I will try to build up a MWE, but as I experienced so far, when I'm reducing my text to an example this behaviour does not appear anymore. It was my guess, maybe someone else had encountered this poblem also and had an idea.

Comment: is the break in the sentence at the top or bottom of a page?  (i know that this is unlikely with the option `[`h]` unless you actually position the code for the figure *inside the paragraph input*.)  it's always best to input code for figures (or any floats) only in vertical mode, i.e., between paragraphs.

Comment: `\lipsum[1]` will issue a `\par` after the lorem ipsum text, try with `\lipsum*[1]` to get the same without that `\par`.